# How can I store a Future <dynamic> data for later use within a program in dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, fetch

I have the following code that does not work:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';


main(){
  String firstTitle = "";
  firstTitle = logic().then((list) => getFirstTitle(list)); // I want to store this data into the variable 
// firstTitle for later use. 
// However my IDE does not recognize the second firstTitle as being linked to the declaration String firstTitle.

}

class MyList {
  static var list = [1];
}

logic() async{
  final result = await http.get('https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=tech+lead');
  final data = json.decode(result.body);
  final myList = [];
  data.forEach((e) {    
    myList.add({"title": e['title'], 'videoId': e['videoId'], 'duration': e['lengthSeconds'], "date": e['publishedText']});
    //print(myList);
  });
  return myList;
}



String getFirstTitle(aList){
  return aList[0]["title"];
}
```

I understand that we await for the data to be fetched from the source but once it is how can I keep as any variable ex: String instead of having it as a Future.

UPDATE: To better illustrate the problem with the IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async await.

```
main() async {
  String firstTitle = "";
  List list=[];
  list=await logic();
  firstTitle = getFirstTitle(list));
}
```

Comment: firstTitle is still not recognized. I've updated the question so you can better understand what I mean.

Comment: @Nassims it's printing Exposing the Techlead (as an ex-fan). what your expecting? you are calling getFirstTitle function it is returning first 0th value only. if you need second value you need to change the code. what you are expecting?